# Are Kurenai's eyes some sort of Doujutsu?

Tags: naruto

Since the start of the series, after the Sharingan and Byakugan had been revealed, Kurenai's eyes seem kind of different from normal eyes and more like the Doujutsu.

[image]

During the attack of the Nine-Tailed Fox on Konoha, her father appeared for the first time in the story. He too possessed similar patterns in his eyes.

So is it some kind of Doujutsu, do her eyes have special abilities similar to the Sharingan or Byakugan, etc.?

Comment: I always thought there were that way to make her unique/gorgeous :P

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually they are not ke-ke-genkai. In [this wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kurenai_Y%C5%ABhi) at the latter part said that:

> *Although her eyes are very distinct, they are not a [dōjutsu](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/D%C5%8Djutsu).*

Dōjutsu (瞳術; English TV "Visual Jutsu"; Literally meaning "Eye Techniques") are genetic ninja abilities that utilise the eyes, granting the wielder ocular abilities. Being a by-product of specific kekkei genkai, dōjutsu are not classified as one of the major jutsu types.

Comment: I have edited my original question and replaced kekei genkai with Dōjutsu. However the question remains still unanswered. Does her eye have special abilities like those of sharingan or byakugan?

Comment: Actually the answer still no. They don't have any special ability.

Answer (score 1):

I like to think it's a form of doūjutsu that is very very weak and I only enhances the users genjutsu skills from 100% to 110%. Kurunai and her father are both very skilled genjutsu specialists so it would make a little sense.

Comment: This question was asked and answered already. Adding new answers to answered questions is not good practice. Your statement would be better off as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

They are not related to sharingan in any way. The are simply because of their genes. Like we have green eyes , brown eyes and stuff. There never has been any canonical opinion about it in anime or in manga. Even so, the manga is coming to an end and still there is no hint of having any powers or any affiliation with the sharingan.

P.S: I mistakenly posted my view on a question labelled duplicate.