# Why are Kurenai's eyes the way they are?

Tags: naruto

I've been reading Naruto, and I've noticed Kurenai's eyes are weird. They look a bit like Sharingan eyes, but there has never been indication they they are at all actually related to the Sharingan. Has there been any explanation for her eyes?

[image]

Comment: related: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4548/are-kurenais-eyes-some-sort-of-doujutsu

Comment: When comparing the question titles, it might not seem like a duplicate. However, this question and the earlier question basically ask the same thing. Both ponder about her unique eyes.

Answer (score 1):

They are not related to sharingan in any way. The are simply because of their genes. Like we have green eyes , brown eyes and stuff. There never has been any canonical opinion about it in anime or in manga. Even so, the manga is coming to an end and still there is no hint of having any powers or any affiliation with the sharingan.